# Which triangulation algorithm creates these triangles

Tags: computational-geometry, triangulation, gl-triangle-strip

I can not figure it out which triangulation algorithm is used to create these triangles in the attached picture. I think it is not delanuay or ear clipping but which polygon triangulation method create these triangles? Any help? [image: picture of triangulation]

Comment: The algorithm appears to be drawing a line from every corner of the shape to every other corner of the shape possible. But it seems to be not drawing lines if the line would cross over other existing lines.

Comment: It seems Iike ear clipping. In any case it is polygon triangulation.

Comment: Why do you exclude ear clipping ?

Comment: Definitely not Delaunay, because no sphere circumscribing a tetrahedron in the triangulation can contain any other point https://cnx.org/contents/WSTSJiRY@10/Molecular-Shapes-and-Surfaces#DelaunayTriangulation

Comment: @weston: this would be constrained Delauney, so the circumcircle rule doesn't hold.

Comment: @YvesDaoust ah thanks

Comment: I exclude ear clipping because I tried same polygon and two triangles vere different from ear clipping as you can see in the my answer

Comment: but it can be another version of an ear clipping method. Do you have any suggestions? It is extremetly important for me to figure out the algorithm

Comment: Couldn't it be ear clipping, but turning the other way round as compared to the one you showed in the comparison image ?

Comment: Any triangulation of a polygon can be obtained by ear clipping.

Comment: Recall that a Delauney triangulation maximizes smallest angles. Many of these polygon triangulations could be improved (wrt that metric) by flipping a few spokes. Thus these are not Delauney triangulations.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is ear clipping because you can see the difference in the attached example. But they are almost same except two triangles.

Difference between ear clipping and triangulation:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Triangle.Net](https://triangle.codeplex.com/) open source library. It features many options including the ability to enrich contour points to maintain a specified triangle aspect ratio.

Comment: And what options would allow L-shaped polygons to be triangulated?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it decomposes the concave polygon into a union of convex polygons, then creates a triangle fan for each of the convex polygons. But it's difficult to be certain.